# rails - How to set value of a select list from a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, formhelper

I want to set the value in a select list based on the value of a variable.

The variable here is `@email_setting.frequency`. 
In the view the code looks like:

```
<%= select('email_setting', 'frequency','<option value="1">Daily</option>
                <option value="2">Immediately</option>
                <option value="3">Every Monday</option>
                <option value="4">Every Tuesday</option>
                <option value="5">Every Wednesday</option>
                <option value="6">Every Thursday</option>
                <option value="7">Every Friday</option>
                <option value="8">Every Saturday</option>
                <option value="9">Every Sunday</option>',
                :class=>'fl-space2 required size-120',
                :selected=>@email_setting.frequency) %>
```

I have tried few variations of the following with no luck.

Any advice on how to get this working right?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check whether the value of @email_setting.frequency. Actually if you give 'email_setting', 'frequency' as the first 2 parameters, the selected value will be `@email_setting.frequency`. I believe it is actually integer(like `1`) and you are providing string as the option value(like `"1"`). That should be the reason why it is not selected. Try

```
<%= select('email_setting', 'frequency', [['Daily', 1],['Immediately', 2], ..], {}, :class=>'fl-space2 required size-120' %>
```

Also the 4th parameter of select is `options` and the 5th parameter is `html_options`. So if you want to give html options like selected, class, you should provide it as 5th parameter by providing 4th parameter `options` as an empty hash. If you really want to give selected also, you should do that like this:

```
<%= select('email_setting', 'frequency', [['Daily', 1],['Immediately', 2], ..], {}, :class=>'fl-space2 required size-120', :selected => @email_setting.frequency %>
```

But the first would be enough in your case.

See [select rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select)